# Spring MVC 3.1 change language i18n based on the request locale language

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, locale

What I would like to do it to display the appropriate language to the user based on his **request.getLocale().getLanguage()**;

So here is what I already have and which is already working fine. Meaning that when I type ?lang=en or ?lang=cn at the end of the URL it displays the appropriate language.

**Application-context.xml**:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">  
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>  
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="cn"></property>
    <property name="cookieName" value="lang"></property>
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

As you can see above, by default I choose to display chinese language "cn". So it displays Chinese when I open the page.
However, in my browser the locale language is "en" so I would like to display the text in English but not in Chinese.

I already tried few things which didn't work:

As you can see above, **CookieLocaleResolver** will create a cookie called "lang" once a ?lang= is selected. So my idea was to create a "**HandlerInterceptorAdapter**" and in the preHandle() I add the cookie to the request hoping that i18n would get it and display the correct language. Also I noticed that in the response header there was "Content-Language=cn" so I even tried to override it with another language:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    Boolean gotLang = false;
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie ck : cookies) {
            if(ck.getName().toString().equals("lang")){
                System.out.println("lang is : " + ck.getValue());
                gotLang = true;
            }
        }// end for each cookie

    }// End if cookie

    //if the cookie Lang does not exist
    //then we set a lang based on the browser lang :D
    if(!gotLang){
        Locale locale = request.getLocale();
        String language = locale.getLanguage();

        if(language.equalsIgnoreCase("en")){
            response.addCookie(new Cookie("lang", "en"));
            response.setHeader("Content-Language","en");
        }else if(language.equalsIgnoreCase("cn")){
            response.addCookie(new Cookie("lang", "cn"));
            response.setHeader("Content-Language","cn");
        }else if(language.equalsIgnoreCase("in")){
            response.addCookie(new Cookie("lang", "in"));
            response.setHeader("Content-Language","in");
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It didn't work.
In the response header I can see the Cookie "lang=en" but the content is still in Chinese. The response header is not overridden it stays the "Content-Language=cn".

However, if I refresh the page, since the cookie "lang=en" was already set then it displays the right language.

I guess I could redirect to the same URL and add ?lang=xx based on the language but I would like to keep the URL clean.

Does anyone would have an idea to make it works?

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation? Use `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` instead of cobbling together your own solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum. How am I supposed to use `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` in my case? thanks for your precious help.

Comment: You want to use the accept header, then use the appropriate `LocaleResolver`. Currently you are using a cookie based one, switch to the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` to always use the one in the request. What is what you are trying to achive? Instead of the default use the one from the header by default (and still allowing a change) or don't allow change and always use the header? Your usecase or what you are trying to achieve isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you M. Deinum. Here is the solution:
The solution is to use the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` as `LocaleResolver`. I should have read the documentation better.

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<!-- Internationalization i18n and l10n -->
<!-- to activate message.properties  -->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">  
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>  
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver">
</bean>
```

This will use the primary locale specified in the "accept-language" header of the HTTP request so the text displayed will be adapted to the language set on the client side.